# Soil Analysis with GEE. How do I look up GPS coordinates?

Tags: google-earth-engine, gps, soil

I am trying to examine the soil order of several of my sampling sites. I have the GPS coordinates for each of these sites but I lack familiarity with GEE. I am looking at "OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02" How do I "ask" GEE to look at the specific areas I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1):

When you have an image and you want data from specific points in it, the tool is [`ee.Image.reduceRegions`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregions). It works for any sort of region, not just points, so you have to specify a reducer to reduce the entire area of the image, but when you want points you can just pick a reducer like `ee.Reducer.median()` or `ee.Reducer.first()` and you'll still get the original single value at that pixel.

```js
var image = ee.Image('OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02');

var results = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: mySamplingSites,   // this should be an ee.FeatureCollection
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
});
```

The result is a `FeatureCollection` and each feature in the collection will have a property for each band in the image, containing the band value at that point.

Comment: Thank you Kevin!!